# Array Not Sorted Correctly

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, nscountedset

I want to sort my array by month and year. I successfully did that with the following code:

```
let formatter : DateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    df.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    return df
}()

 let arrayOfMonths = ["June 2018", "July 2019", "June 2018", "July 2018", "January 2015", "June 2017"]

let sortedArrayOfMonths = arrayOfMonths.sorted( by: { formatter.date(from: $0)! < formatter.date(from: $1)! })
//prints ["January 2015", "June 2017", "June 2018", "June 2018", "July 2018", "July 2019"]
```

Now that I have my array sorted in the correct order I want to count how many of the same months I have. I successfully do that with the following code:

```
var counts = [Int]()
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: sortedArrayOfMonths)
for item in countedSet {
    counts.append(countedSet.count(for: item))
    print("\(item) : \(countedSet.count(for: item))")
}
```

The problem is that now my array is out of order. The following code prints:

```
 January 2015 : 1
 July 2018 : 1
 June 2017 : 1
 July 2019 : 1
 June 2018 : 2
```

How can I re-sort my array? I'm not sure why it's out of order. You can put the code in `Playgrounds` and test it out. Thanks

Comment: A `Set` is unordered by definition. You might build your *NSCountedArray* yourself 

Comment: Do you have an example? I googled `NSCountedArray` and nothing showed up.

Comment: →  ← There is no `NSCountedArray`. *build ... yourself* means you have to write the code for example with a loop.

Comment: @TylerMiddleton What vadian means is that it's normal because the `NSCountedSet` as its name states does count, and because it's a set, it's unordered. What you are trying to what (which doesn't exists) is a `NSCountedArray`, an array that count and since it's an array, it keeps the order.

Comment: Why don't you use dictionary?

Comment: this `let sorted = countedSet.allObjects.sorted(by: {formatter.date(from: $0 as! String)! < formatter.date(from: $1 as! String)!})` will give the sorted array again. But i don't think you need that as you already have the sorted array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after messing around with the code on playgrounds. I found a workable solution. First we sort the array:

```
let formatter : DateFormatter = {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    df.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
    return df
}()

let arrayOfMonths = ["June 2018", "July 2019", "June 2018", "July 2018", "January 2015", "June 2017"]

let sortedArrayOfMonths = arrayOfMonths.sorted( by: { formatter.date(from: $0)! < formatter.date(from: $1)! })
print(sortedArrayOfMonths)
```

After the array is sorted we will loop through that array and add the date to a new array, `dqw`, only if that date does not previously exist in the new array. Then we add the number of times that date occurs to another array `counts`

```
var counts = [Int]()
var dqw = [String]()
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: sortedArrayOfMonths)
var i = 0
for item in sortedArrayOfMonths {
    if dqw.contains(item) {
        print("already exist")
    } else {
        dqw.append(item)
        counts.append(countedSet.count(for: item))
    }
}
```

Now we can loop the new `dqw` array we created and the `counts` array and print our results.

```
while i < dqw.count {
   print("\(dqw[i]) : \(counts[i])")
   i += 1
}
```

Results:

```
January 2015 : 1
June 2017 : 1
June 2018 : 2
July 2018 : 1
July 2019 : 1
```

Comment: Bad solution. You have sorted array. You have `countedSet` which knows how many occurrences for any item inside sorted array. Why you have to create two more arrays where `dqw` is the same array as sortedArray. `counts` is just an array of occurrences count which sortedSet already know. In the for loop you can simply print the result as `for item in sortedArrayOfMonths { print("\(item) : \(countedSet.count(for: item))") }`

Comment: @kamran Actually it is a great solution!! What you are suggestion is not accurate because you get duplicated dated that way. I make a new array because I am filtering to make sure I only end up with one of each month. Take my code and put in a playground and you'll see what I'm saying. ☺️ There might be other ways to solve this problem but this is the best way I have found for now